# Get fields with documents in Elasticsearch with Pig-Hadoop

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-pig

I am using pig-hadoop to read documents from my Elasticsearch servers. The documents look something like this

```
{
    "_index": "sa-test",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "AUujDbzSR5FzDDhtC1LH",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "fieldA": "....",
        "fieldB": "....",
        "fieldC": ".....",
        "fieldE": "....."
    }
}, {
    "_index": "sa-test",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "AUujDbzSR5FzXXXtC1LH",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "fieldB": "....",
        "fieldC": ".....",
        "fieldD": "....."
    }
}
```

which is fine. The problem occurs when I try to read this data in via Pig

```
-- load the data in
raw_logs = LOAD 'sa-test' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.query=?q=someFilter', 'es.mapping.date.rich=false');
-- for now just dump it
DUMP raw_logs;
```

this yields data in the form

```
(fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldE)
(fieldB,fieldC,fieldD)
```

now at this point, I don't have any idea which fields were missing or which ones are present since data in each row in inconsistent. This is proving a problem for further processing.

Is there any way I can get field values along with the rows or some sort of mapping that can tell me which value belongs to which field. Something of the sort

```
(A=fieldA,B=fieldB,C=fieldC,E=fieldE)
(A=fieldB,C=fieldC,D=fieldD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging down, found the solution, posting here for reference if anyone finds.

You can specify a schema when loading data into pig:

```
raw_logs = LOAD 'sa-test' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.query=?q=someFilter', 'es.mapping.date.rich=false') AS (fieldA:...,fieldB:...,fieldC:...,fieldD:...fieldE:...);
```

ES-Hadoop will match up document fields from Elasticsearch with the provided schema for Pig. At that point, you can refer to the fields by name:

```
all_fieldA_values = FOREACH raw_logs GENERATE fieldA;
```